# How to change Persistence Unit dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I have a Spring MVC + Hibernate + JPA app. Also have 4 different Schemas in my db with similar tables. (for different companies) .

> Now when I'm using my Hibernate app, can i switch Persistence Unit so
>   that I can use same the form (with the same content) to save data in
>   all four Schemas?

I'm aware that i can switch persistence unit at run time, but i want to be able to use the already loaded forms to save data to all four Schemas by changing the persistence unit.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to understand your problem: of course you can change the PersistentUnit used at runtime with the [Persistence#createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory(java.lang.String)) method.

But if you want to

> save data to all four Schemas

Then you should repeat your operation (persist I guess) four times (for example in a private method taking the persistence unit name as parameter).

You could introduce a form cache if you want to reuse *the already loaded forms*, but this is a software architecture question.

As suggested [in the Java EE 5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbrm.html#bnbrp), on a software design point of view, having a form depending directly on the JPA layer is not a best practice. The other answer suggests it: a DAO could be the solution. All is about your DAOs lifecyle.

The Core JEE patterns book [suggests it](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/DataAccessObject.htm) (the online reference only mentions briefly the topic, the printed book is better): associating DAOs with a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is a good idea. You could recycle the EntityManagerFactory or anything you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem some time ago.
I had 2 identical schemas - application had to persist to first or second depending on some logic.
It was pure Hibernate, but talking in terms of JPA I will suggest to have 4 persistence units defined in your persistence.xml:

*persistence.xml*

```
<persistence-unit name="PU1">
  ...
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="PU2">
  ...
</persistence-unit>

[...]
```

and DAO class that has injected EntityManager proxies - each for different PU:

```
@Repository
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU1") 
    private EntityManager em1;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU2") 
    private EntityManager em2;

    ...

    public void saveToPU1(MyEntity e) {
        em1.persist(e);
    }
    public void saveToPU2(MyEntity e) {
        em2.persist(e);
    }
    ...

}
```

Of course `em1` annotated with `@PersistenceContext(unitName="PU1")` is Spring's proxy to Hibernate session and becomes open and bound with current thread only if that thread tries to use it.